# Checkboxes in MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, checkbox

I have been attempting to incorporate checkboxes that will be displayed on a list - the goal is to be able to select multiple checkboxes (or select all) and delete those rows. It took a little searching, but I found a great method to use, however I have an issue with the query.

Here is my ViewModel

```
 public class RecipeWrapper
{
    public List<RecipeSelect> recipes { get; set; }
    public RecipeWrapper()
    {
        this.recipes = new List<RecipeSelect>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> getSelection()
    {
        List<int> ids = new List<int>();
        foreach (var n in recipes)
        {
            if (n.selection == true)
            {
                ids.Add(n.Recipe_ID);
            }
        }
        return ids;
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel RecipeSelect (instantiated as a List in above ViewModel)

```
    public class RecipeSelect
{
    public bool selection { get; set; }
    public int Recipe_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Difficulty { get; set; }
    public string Meal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Cook_Time { get; set; }
    public string Directions { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller method that performs the deletion:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteChecked(RecipeWrapper wrap)
    {
        var selectedIDs = wrap.getSelection();


        **var selectedRecipes = from m in db.Recipes
                              where selectedIDs.Contains(m.Recipe_ID)
                              select m;**



        foreach (var n in selectedRecipes)
        {
            db.Recipes.Remove(n);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I have debugged the program and determined that my EditorTemplate is correct and data is passed properly to the controller. However, the bold text containing the query does not return any results. If I take out the where clause, it returns all results and the subsequent code deletes all rows, as it should. This leads me to think there is something wrong with my query. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

*Edited: I should give credit where it is due - [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706728/ASP-NET-MVC-Display-an-HTML-Table-with-Checkboxes?msg=4751584#xx4751584xx) offers a great explanation of incorporating checkboxes on a list in MVC. Highly recommended as I struggled searching for a good method for a few days.

Comment: I assume that you have check that this line: var selectedIDs = wrap.getSelection(); works correctly (I mean it returns an appropriate list of ids?)

Comment: Yes, I manually looped through while debugging and it does return the proper ids.